# How to get single row in table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a solid bar on top of three cells.  Example is viewable in Chrome [here on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/smdh26pk/)

This seemed like a straightforward thing to do with (legacy?) tables, but I'm not able to get the first row with a single cell to cover the max width of the table rows.

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: pink;">a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: The title asks about getting a single row in a table, the text starts asking about a solid bar, then adds that ideally `div`s be used and not a table at all, and the example presents a linear gradient that does not look solid. The question should be rewritten, or probably better deleted and a new question posted, starting with a title that reflects the *problem*, not an assumed second-class solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colspan` is what you need.

Just apply `colspan="3"` to the pink cell like this:

```
<td style="background-color: pink;" colspan="3">a</td>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/399snxz4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want a row with a bar above the ABC row. You can do this by specifying a colspan on the `<td>` of the row above the ABC row:

```
<td colspan="3"><your bar></td>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/399snxz4/2/

For more information on colspan, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp